Django Prefetch Related Still Queries
I have the function
def selected_location_equipment(self):
    qs = (Equipment.objects
            .prefetch_related('service_logs')
            .all())

    return qs

That returns a queryset with a few related fields grabbed.
The problem is that when i access the prefetched data later in my code, it executes a query again.
Ive stepped through the Django code and can see where it is checking the cache for the .all() in one spot and doesnt query, but then when its called here, it's almost like the cache is cleared.
Debug Toolbar shows a query for each iteration of the loop as well.
for e in equipments:
   last_service = list(e.service_logs.all())[-1]
   for log in e.service_logs.all():
        # do other stuff
        ...

Here's the basic model definition for Equipment
class ServiceLog(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                  related_name='service_logs')


Where does equipments originates from?

This code doesn't execute the query twice - confirmed by Debug Toolbar and by connection.queries. There has to be something else going on, maybe in the code we don't see.

@willeM_VanOnsem selected_location_equipment

@MargoGrig the looping code runs directly after the selected_location_equipment function. its a rather small view thats not doing anything but getting dashboard data. Its for sure wild, only project this has happened on.

You want to fetch only the last service log per equipment and avoid unnecessary memory consumption, you can also use annotate() or Prefetch with filtering:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

# Prefetch only the latest service log
qs = Equipment.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('service_logs', queryset=ServiceLog.objects.order_by('-id'), to_attr='prefetched_service_logs')
)

for e in qs:
    last_service = e.prefetched_service_logs[0] if e.prefetched_service_logs else None


So i dont exactly just want the last log, I just dont want the prefetched field to query again. Im using all the logs elsewhere, but the easiest place to show the issue was when im grabbing the last one.

Probably the issue is that you are using .all() in the loop making query to run again. If you want to avoid extra queries you fetch the data only once:
for e in equipments:
   service_logs = list(e.service_logs.all()) 

   last_service = service_logs[-1]  
  
   for log in service_logs:
      ...

Although, it is strange that debug Toolbar shows a query for each iteration because Django should cache the result according to the docs. If you do actions to a log during iterate the queries might be connected to that, though.
